# How to create a GitHub repository from CLI

Tags: git, github

Is there any git command/script to create new GitHub repository from CLI?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it (change REPO and USERNAME):

```
curl -d '{"name": "REPO"}' -u USERNAME https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

If you are using two factor auth, you'll also need to add this as part of the curl invocation:

```
-H X-GitHub-OTP:123456
```

Replace 123456 with the current 2FA value from your token generator (you'll need to be quick).